# This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations?

Tags: discussion

[image]

I happen to see the user was suspended, how do I know some rules about this?

> This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends on Aug 13 at 2:08.

Mathematica.SE also has the similar limits? right?

Comment: If you click on ["temporarily suspended"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), you'll see some more information on user suspensions. The moderators there (or anywhere) are not going to tell you the reasons why the account was suspended, as it is generally considered to be private between the user and the moderators (and SE).

Comment: @rm-rf I wonder Mathematica.SE whether there are similar rules! so I asked here——！Because I haven't saw some users in Mathematica.SE be suspended.

Comment: We're all part of the Stack Exchange network, so the rules are the same everywhere, although enforcement of the rules might vary. Yes, there have been several account suspensions here.

Comment: @rm-rf ok,,,I just curious about some rules.   What I can image is that if I uploaded too images(this maybe possible for me)?
Or shouting abuse frequently?

Comment: You needn't worry about too many images – no one keeps track of it and it's not like their servers are going to break because you uploaded 20kB more than you should have. On the other hand, if you're running a malicious bot that repeatedly uploads images, then...

Comment: @rm-rf I've tried the Szabolcs's ImageUploader which fixed by halirutan today, pretty good. But the bad thing is my usage...If I edit my post in Notebook for 10 times then convert it to SE. If there are 5 output become images, then 10 times will upload 50 images.

Comment: Perhaps you should be rethinking your use of images then? I've answered close to 500 questions and I don't recall ever having to use 5 images in one post... Also, don't upload each time you edit something. Upload only when you're finished and satisfied with the result.

Comment: @rm-rf haha, just one possible thing not happen yet.

Comment: Try to avoid uploading too many images, because they will be stored forever and never deleted. However, although it might cause problems for SE in the distant future, this will not get you suspended. Grounds for that (at Mma.SE) are repeated rudeness to other users, asking large numbers of exceptionally stupid questions, or generally causing a severe nuisance and disruption to the site. Other sites, Math.SE included, seem to have a lot of users who do not get on well with one another, so these things happen more frequently elsewhere. So far we've been lucky not to have that happen here.